# BulkSynchronize a subset of data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-extensions

I'm using EF extensions and want to synchronise a subset of data.

For example my table:

```
|Type|Value|
------------
|A   |1    |
|B   |2    |
|B   |3    |
|A   |4    |
|A   |5    |
```

New data comes

```
|Type|Value|
------------
|B   |6    |
|B   |7    |
|B   |8    |
```

And I want to replace all Bs without touching As to get

```
|Type|Value|
------------
|A   |1    |
|B   |6    |
|B   |7    |
|B   |8    |
|A   |4    |
|A   |5    |
```

Is there any way to achieve that using bulk operations?

Comment: What have you tried to do?

Comment: I've tried `await _context.BulkSynchronizeAsync(users, options => options.ColumnPrimaryKeyExpression = type => type.Type);` but it removes everything else except for the new data. `BulkMerge` doesn't delete old data at all.

Comment: @ArturShamsutdinov why downvote?

Comment: @viveknuna because instead of answering my question you are giving some random ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)

You are looking for the `ColumnSynchronizeDeleteKeySubsetExpression` options.

For example, only `type` that will be equal to a type from your `new data` (so only `B` type) will be deleted:

```
ctx.BulkSynchronize(list, options => options.ColumnSynchronizeDeleteKeySubsetExpression = c  => c.Type);
```

Let me know if you need some help to implement it.

Comment: Thanks! I actually found this solution yesterday myself and it works. Thanks for a great library btw.